# I'm trying to get the fields of a form to stack when on mobile but stay side-by-side when on desktop (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a form for a website with SMS opt in and I'm trying to get the two fields to stack when on mobile but remain side-by-side on desktop using display: flex. I'm ~relatively~ new to web development and I've tried everything I can think of, including using display: block instead.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 id="top-text">NEVER MISS A DROP</h4>
        <h4
          id="explanation"
          style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center"
        >
          FOR TEXT MESSAGE ALERTS & POTENTIAL EARLY ACCESS, SIGN UP BELOW
        </h6>
      </div>
      <form id="form">
        <div
          style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center"
        >
          <select
            style=" margin: 2px; width: 100%; height: 30px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center"
          >
            <option>(+1) United States</option>
            <option>(+44) United Kingdom</option>
            <option>(+52) Mexico</option>
            <option>(+49) Germany</option>
            <option>(+354) Iceland</option>
          </select>
          <input
            style=" text-align: center; height: 25px; width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center"
            id="phone-number"
            name="phone-number"
            placeholder="Please Enter Phone Number"
            type="number"
            />
        </div>
        <div
          style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center"
        >
          <button style="width: 300px; margin-top: 5px;" type="submit">CONFIRM SUBSCRIPTION</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <p id="disclaimer" style="font-size: x-small;" >* I consent to recieve recurring automated marketing by text message through an automatic telephone dialing system. Consent is not a condition to purchase. STOP to cancel, HELP for help. Message and Data rates apply. View Privacy Policy & ToS</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#top-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Athletic;
}

#explanation {
  font-family: Athletic;
  font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Athletic;
  src: url(Athletic.TTF);
}

#country-select {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#phone-number {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Athletic;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 170px;
}
button:hover {
  background: #343a40;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-25,
  .col-75,
  input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

/* #form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
} */
/* #submit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add flex-wrap to the form and it will move the item(s) to the next line.

Here's how:

```
#form {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This made it so it's always stacked. I still want it to be inline when the screen size is larger, but once you get closer to mobile size I want it to be stacked.